# compare fasta sequences in pairs and collect metrics

Tags: phylogenetics, fasta, phylogeny, assembly, blast

I have 96  fasta files (A1, A2, A3...) from one  plasmid assembly pipeline, and I have another 96 fasta  files (B1, B2, B3 ...) from another plasmid assembly pipeline.
I would like to compare pair wise (A1 to B1, A2 to B2, A3 to B3 etc) and collect some metrics to see how this two assembly method differs.

I am thinking of doing blastn -query A1 -subject B1, but this created a lot visual alignment, rather than detailed align metrics.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: OK, I think maybe I will just stay with blastn and do this: blastn -query A1 -subject B1 |grep -E "Score|Identities|Strand" >res_A1_B1
 Then I will get report like this  in res_A1_B1, Score = 1.048e+04 bits (5674),  Expect = 0.0
 Identities = 5674/5674 (100%), Gaps = 0/5674 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Minus
 I can further collect them into tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy; just use output `format 6`, this gives you a nice table that's easy to parse:

```
blastn -db plasmid2.db -query plasmid1.fasta -evalue 1e-6 -outfmt "6 pident evalue bitscore"
```

I don't know what parameters you prefer.

```
... "6 pident evalue bitscore" ...
```

You just edit the `pident`, `evalue` and `bitscore` above.  You might want to place `staxid` or something to tell you what it is. A selection of parameters are as follows:

> staxid ssciname qseqid sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore qcovs sstrand

You might want to make the command a bit fancier

```
blastn -db plasmid2.db -query plasmid1.fasta -evalue 1e-7 -outfmt "6 pident evalue bitscore" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n >> myplasmid.txt
```